# Jquery Autocomplete with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have been messing with this for too long trying to get it to work. Can anyone please see if you have any pointers.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="autocomplete.css" />      
        <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {                
                $( "#materials" ).autocomplete({
                    source: "autocomplete.php",
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="demo">

            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="materials">Materials: </label>
                <input id="materials" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- End demo -->            
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php file is

```
require_once "db_con.php"; // Database connection, I know this works.
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q)
    return;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM materials WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'"; 
$rsd = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['name']; // I know this all returns correctly
    echo json_encode($cname); // First time I have ever used json, error might be here.
}
```

I am trying to have a webpage with an autocomplete powered by Jquery that is supplied data from mysql using PHP. Simples. Only its not working...

Anyone have any ideas what I am missing ?

Regards

---- EDIT ----

In order to check this was working I completed the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="autocomplete.css" />      
        <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {                
                $( "#materials" ).autocomplete({
                    source: <?php
include_once 'db_con.php';
$sql = "SELECT name FROM materials";
$rsd = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
echo '[';
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    echo "'" . $rs['name'] . "', "; //add results to array
}
echo ']';
?>,
                        minLength: 2
                    });
                });
        </script>
        <div class="demo">

            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="materials">Materials: </label>
                <input id="materials" />
            </div>


        </div><!-- End demo -->        
    </body>
</html>
```

Which works perfectly. So good infact I think im going to keep this code not quite how its supposed to work but...

Comment: That edit is the most horrific way to build JSON strings. try: `$json = array(); while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) { $json[] = $rs['name']; } echo json_encode($json);`

Comment: its a bit late to answer but if you want to read a detailed tutorial about autocomplete in jQuery using php and MySQL please visit this link https://programmerblog.net/autocomplete-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP is all wrong:

```
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['name']; // I know this all returns correctly
    echo json_encode($cname); // First time I have ever used json, error might be here.
}
```

Should be:

```
$cname = array();
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname[]['label'] = $rs['name']; // I know this all returns correctly
    break;
}
echo json_encode($cname); // First time I have ever used json, error might be here.
```

`label` is the default label field within an array row that is used by jqueryautocomplete (I believe). Also the return must be an array of arrays each array row representing a match.

You can make it more complicated by adding a value field for what to make the textbox to actually equal to by doing:

```
$cname = array();
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname[]['label'] = $rs['name']; // I know this all returns correctly
    $cname[]['value'] = $rs['id'];
    break;
}
echo json_encode($cname); // First time I have ever used json, error might be here.
```

Of course I don't think your actually wanting the `break;` I put this in because:

```
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['name']; // I know this all returns correctly
    echo json_encode($cname); // First time I have ever used json, error might be here.
}
```

Denotes to me that you are actually returning a single row from your results. If you are not and are actually returning all results then take the `break;` out.

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP part, maybe try something like that:

```
$res = array();  //create a new array
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
  $res[] = (string)$rs['name']; //add results to array, casted as string
}
header('Content-type: application/json'); //add JSON headers (might work w/o)
echo json_encode($res);  //output array as JSON
```

...that way you should have all results in one array like
`['name1', 'name2', 'name3']`

Comment: try `source: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']` in the JS part to make sure the jQuery part works. If not, are you getting any errors on the JS console?

Comment: good idea thank you. It works with ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], so I assume it must be the php end. Thanks this at least has helped me reduce 50% of where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Its works for me

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#materials").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        autoFill:true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. To the point where the text box doesn't even seem to call the jquery function as the loading gif is never visible.

Comment: Your textbox id is materials? if not then apply id materials and check it.

Comment: @PaulChambers you can also write this function in ready() function.I have updated my answer check it

Answer (score 0):

to handle a json answer from a php ajax call i customize the source function and handle the result myself this way:

```
$(function() {                
    $( "#materials" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.post("autocomplete.php", {
                term: request.term
            }, function(data){
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    data.push({
                        label: "No result found",
                    });
                }
                response($.map(data, function(item){
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }))
            }, "json");
        },
        minLength: 2,
        dataType : "json"});
});
```